# Scrollable table arrow/indicator Angular material?

Tags: css, angular, html-table, scroll, user-experience

I am looking for a user friendly way to:

- Indicate a table is too wide, and thus scrollable, even when the bottom scrollbar is not visible yet
- Allow the user to scroll this table easily, also on mobile
- It does **not** need IE support :)

I found this jquery plugin, which seems to handle that fine:

https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Mobile-friendly-Scrollable-Table-Plugin-For-jQuery-ScrolTable.html

[image]

I would prefer a pure CSS or TS/angular solution, as I would rather not incorporate jQuery when not needed.

Are there any, more modern alternatives? Is there a standard UX approach that I missed?